# Style List Div to have different colors based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a form on a page that includes a dropdown, I want the background color for each div to be different depending on the dropdown selection. For instance, if the user selects `Seedy Fruit`, I want the list div to be green, and `Non Seedy Fruit` to be Red.

How can I implement this?

**FruitListRender.Jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FruitForm from "./FruitForm";
import FruitList from "./FruitList";

const FruitListRender = () => {
  const [newFruit, setNewFruit] = useState("");
  const [fruits, setFruitList] = useState([]);
  const [fruitType, setFruitType] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <FruitForm
          newFruit={newFruit}
          setNewFruit={setNewFruit}
          fruits={fruits}
          setFruitList={setFruitList}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <FruitList fruits={fruits} setFruitList={setFruitList} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default FruitListRender;
```

**FruitListForm**

```
import React from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const FruitListForm = ({
  newFruit,
  setNewFruit,
  fruits,
  setFruitsList,
}) => {
  const addFruits = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setFruitList([...fruits, { id: uuidv4(), name: newFruit, type: fruitType }]);
    setNewFruits("");
  };
  return (
    <form className="fruitform" onSubmit={addFruits}>
      <div>
        <input
          value={newFruit}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name of Fruit"
          onChange={(e) => setNewFruit(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="fruitform__addfruit">
          <select
            value={fruitType}
            placeholder="Fruit Type"
            className="fruitform__dropdown"
            onChange={(e) => setFruitType(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>
              Fruit Type
            </option>
              <option value="Seedy Fruit">Seedy Fruit</option> {" "}
            <option value="Non Seedy Fruit">Non Seedy Fruit</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default FruitListForm;
```

**FruitList.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

const FruitList = ({ fruits = [], setFruitList }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {fruits.map((fruit) => (
        <ul key={fruit.id}>
          <li className="fruit-list">
            <p>{fruit.name}</p>
            <p>{fruit.type}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default FruitList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you map the selection to a `fruitOption` variable, probably by using a hook, then

```
const optionToClass = {"seedy fruit":"seedy", "non seedy fruit":"non-seedy"}
<li className={"fruit-list "+(optionToClass[fruitOption])}>
```

and in your CSS file,

```
.seedy {
  background-color: green
}
...
```

Or you could just do it inline, if you prefer.